# max-height responsive not being applied

Tags: jquery, css, html, responsive-design

I'm learning how to make a responsive navigation bar. 
in order to understand check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4Yr7J/

if you expand the result you will see a different menu but when its minimized (as shown by default by jsfiddle) you only see a bar called "menu" this bar is supposed to grow when clicked due to adding the following class

```
.showing{
    max-height: 20em;
}
```

through

```
    <script>
        $('.handle').on('click', function(){
            $('#main_menu nav ul').toggleClass('showing');
        });
    </script>
```

the class is being added just fine. However, the property max-height:20em is not being recognized. I noticed the dev tool shows it as crossed out. I don't know what is causing this but any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Revised JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/htzwf/)

The problem is that when it comes to CSS,

```
#main_menu nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 0;
}
```

takes precedence over

```
.showing {
    max-height: 20em;
}
```

because it is more specific.  One way we can fix this is by replacing it with:

```
#main_menu nav ul.showing {
    max-height: 20em;
}
```

which is much more specific than #main_menu nav ul, meaning that this CSS rule will take precedence over the max-height:0.